# Want to read a file from line(1) to line(n) in php

Tags: php, file, fread

I have a PHP script to read a file from line n to line (n).I mean I will select the lines from the drop-down list and the script will read that file.I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411961/how-to-read-a-file-from-line-x-to-line-y-with-php) and some other but not solving my problem.

PHP

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $selected_file = $_POST['files'];
    $from_line = $_POST['from_line'];
    $to_line = $_POST['to_line'];

    $file_open = fopen($selected_file,"r+") or die('Fail to open a file');

    $file_array = file($selected_file);

    $read = fread($file_open,3000); 
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<form name="read" method="post" action="">
<table>

<tr><td>Select File</td><td><select name="files" style="width:183px;">
<?php
 foreach (scandir('.') as $file){
    $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   if($extension == 'txt'){
 echo"<option>".$file."</option>";
 }}
?>
</select></td>
<tr><td>From</td><td><select name="from_line" style="width:183px">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>To</td><td><select name="to_line" style="width:183px">

<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Read" /></td></tr>

<tr><td></td></tr>


</table>
</form>
```

**What I want**

I will select values from the drop-down lists and script will read in that range.For example from line 4 to line 8

Correct my script if I am wrong ...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple logic with `file` function. Have a look on below solution:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $selected_file = $_POST['files'];
    $from_line = $_POST['from_line'];
    $to_line = $_POST['to_line'];



    $file_array = file($selected_file);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($file_array); $i++){
        if($i >= ($from_line -1) && $i < ($to_line)){
            echo $file_array[$i];
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

It will echo required lines from the file.

Comment: array will start from 0 index that's why we need to compare with `$from_line -1`

Answer (score 0):

`file()` function will return file contents as an array of strings (if no error occurred).
The first line in that array is in the default starting position (`0`).
 So, this condition should be considered when getting the expected range.
For such input boundaries: from `4` - to `8` - it should be: from `3` - to `7`

 
To get range of elements(strings) from array use `array_slice` function:

```
...

$file_array = file($selected_file);
$len = $to_line - $from_line;
$strings_slice = array_slice($file_array, $from_line - 1, $len);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. this would definitely help you.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $selected_file = $_POST['files'];
    $from_line = $_POST['from_line'];
    $to_line = $_POST['to_line'];

    $file_open = fopen($selected_file,"rb") or die('Fail to open a file')
    $i=1;
    while ($line = fgets($file_open, 1000)) {
        if($i>=$from_line && $i<=$to_line){
            echo $line.'<br/>';
        }
        $i++; 
        }
    }
?>
```